# String not properly being extracted in java method

Tags: java

I have a method that is supposed to extract categories from a string.
Anywhere it finds `category:<something>` in a long string, it's supposed to be able to extract that and print but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My method seems accurate. But nothing is being printed. Please advise. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

The String:

```
String str = "We have a large inventory of things in our warehouse falling in "
+ "the category:apperal and the slightly "
+ "more in demand category:makeup along with the category:furniture and ….";
```

The method that's supposed to extract categories:

```
public static void printCategories(String string){
     int i = 0;
      while (true) {
        int found = string.indexOf("category", i);
        if (found == -1) break;
        int start = found + 8; // start of actual category
        int end = string.indexOf(":", start);
        System.out.println(string.substring(start, end));
        i = end + 1;  // advance i to start the next iteration
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line ends up making end the same as start because : is exactly at the location of start:

```
        int end = string.indexOf(":", start);
```

What you want to do is look for a space, and start one more character past category:

```
        int i = 0;
      while (true) {
        int found = string.indexOf("category", i);
        if (found == -1) break;
        int start = found + 9; // start of actual category
        int end = string.indexOf(" ", start);
        System.out.println(string.substring(start, end));
        i = end + 1;  // advance i to start the next iteration
      }
```

Comment: I don't understand why I need the space? I'm searching for the colon. What's the space going to do? There is no space between `category:item`

Comment: @Doublespeed to determine the ends of apparel, makeup or furniture words in your example

Answer (score 2):

Seems, that your start position is equals to index of colon element, then you extract the end of the category.

`found` is equals to start position of substring `category` And the `start` position is equals to `found+8` and equals to position of the colon(`:`). Then you call

```
int end = string.indexOf(":", start);
```

Index of colon is equals to start and you get start and end equals while trying to get substring. You have to change the colon to whitespace or whatever you have to determine the end of category in the code above.

Comment: Why do I have to change colon to empty space? The assignment asks for colon

Comment: To get the end of category value substring, because you are looking for the category name, not the category word,I suppose. And I mean change it only in the int end = string.indexOf(":", start);, as it's said

Comment: @Doublespeed In Your case, whitespace is needed to get the end of apperal word. If you leave a colon, you will not get the end of this word, but anything else

Comment: Nothing special, you just looking for substring starting from the colon position and till the whitespace

Answer (score 0):

start and end point the same index, so noting gets printed in console.

```
public static void printCategories(String string) {
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        int found = string.indexOf("category", i);
        if (found == -1)
            break;
        int start = found + 9; // start of actual category --> incremented one position to omit `:`
        int end = string.indexOf(" ", start); // added space to split the word after category
        System.out.println(string.substring(start, end));
        i = end + 1; // advance i to start the next iteration
    }
}
```